# AS3: count items in an array element, then add them back into the array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, for-loop

My objective is to take an array that looks like this:

```
    [{"ct_start_year":"2013","ct_start_month":"07", ct_prog: "1"},     
    {"ct_start_year":"2013","ct_start_month":"07", ct_prog: "2"},
    {"ct_start_year":"2013","ct_start_month":"08", ct_prog: "1"},
    {"ct_start_year":"2012","ct_start_month":"03", ct_prog: "1"},
    {"ct_start_year":"2012","ct_start_month":"04", ct_prog: "1"}]
```

Then write a loop that identifies the programs ("ct_prog") in each year ("ct_start_year"), evaluate the month ("ct_start_month") and if there is more than 1 program in that month, add them together to produce a new array that looks like this:

```
    [{"ct_start_year":"2013","ct_start_month":"07", ct_prog: **"3"**}, 
{"ct_start_year":"2013","ct_start_month":"08", ct_prog: "1"},
    {"ct_start_year":"2012","ct_start_month":"03", ct_prog: "1"},
    {"ct_start_year":"2013","ct_start_month":"04", ct_prog: "1"}]
```

As you can see, one of the lines in this example has 'disappeared' because the "ct_prog" with values 1 and 2 became 3 since the month was the same ("07") for that year ("2013").  If there was only one program for that month, as in the case of 2012, the line remains unchanged.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<date_test.length; ++i) {

      if (date_test[i].ct_prog >= 1 && date_test[i].ct_start_year == "2013"){

        if (date_test[i].ct_start_month == date_test[i].ct_start_month){

        trace (date_test[i].ct_prog + date_test[i].ct_start_year + date_test[i].ct_start_month);   
    }
    }
```

But the results from the trace are unsatisfying because in the case of "2013", not only are the programs in the "07" month returned but so is the program in the "08" month - I was hoping that the second "if" statement would at least filter that out.

Also, I remain uncertain how to 1) add the values in the ct_prog element for the "07" month, to produce the "3" value in the new array; and 2) how to add that value to the new array and eliminate the "extra" line in the array which is now unnecessary.

Any help, much appreciated, as always!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to use a Hash Table or something similar.

You can have your 'key' to be ct_start_year + ct_start_month (concatenated as a string to be super simple) and your 'value' should be the 'addition' of all the values that you can find with that key.

The code looks like:

```
{
    var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    for(var i:uint = 0; i < date_test.lenght; ++i)
    {
        var key:String = date_test[i].ct_start_year + date_test[i].ct_start_month;

        if (dict[key] == null)
          dict[key] = 0;

        dict[key] += date_test[i].ct_prog
    }
}
```

This data structure helps a lot with problems like this (where you have an easily identifiable key to group objects or values under).

Comment: Thanks!  I have seen implementations of Dictionaries and Maps so I am not surprised that this could be a solution.  I will give that a try!